# Extract character from one column and populate them in 2 different columns ssis derived column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a column ProductDetails which has values such as

```
j Jameson Mbc 6.5, abc 8 abc blah
Napa california Mbc 1 abc 3.5
Washington k Mbc 2.5 abc 6
New york city is awesome
```

i have thousands of records

I want to populate 2 other columns Mbc and abc as below

```
Mbc
6.5
1
2.5

abc
8
3.5
6
```

I tried `(DT_STR,10,1252)substring(ProductDetails, findstring(“Mbc”, ProductDetails,1)+4,3)`

For abc= `(DT_STR,10,1252)substring(ProductDetails, findstring(“abc”, ProductDetails,1)+4,3)`

I get result and some values are coming as `1C` or `2b` etc , just want numbers no characters

For column value such as 
`New york city is awesome` we just want to populate it with `Null` etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"abc" column**

```
FINDSTRING( [ProductDetails],"abc", 1 ) > 0 ? SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([ProductDetails], FINDSTRING( [ProductDetails],"abc", 1 ) + 4 , 3),1,LEN( SUBSTRING([ProductDetails], FINDSTRING( [ProductDetails],"abc", 1 ) + 4 , 3) ) - FINDSTRING( SUBSTRING([ProductDetails], FINDSTRING( [ProductDetails],"abc", 1 ) + 4 , 3) ," ",1)) : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

**"Mbc" column**

```
FINDSTRING( [ProductDetails],"Mbc", 1 ) > 0 ? SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([ProductDetails], FINDSTRING( [ProductDetails],"Mbc", 1 ) + 4 , 3),1,LEN( SUBSTRING([ProductDetails], FINDSTRING( [ProductDetails],"Mbc", 1 ) + 4 , 3) ) - FINDSTRING( SUBSTRING([ProductDetails], FINDSTRING( [ProductDetails],"Mbc", 1 ) + 4 , 3) ," ",1)) : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

Comment: Late, but thanks, it did work.I did not log in a while.